# Pass two parameters in $.ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem. I want to pass two variables from PHP to $.ajax success function

I have this code written in JS:

```
$.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:path,
                        data: "value="+info,
                        success:function(data,data1)
                        {
                            if(data==1)
                            {
                                $(id).css("backgroundColor","green");
                                $(id).attr("readonly","readonly");
                                $(image).attr("src",data1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $(id).css("backgroundColor","red");
                            }
                        } 
                });
```

And my PHP code is :

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) and !empty($_POST['value']))
{
$result=0;
$image="src/photo1.jpg";
$value=trim($_POST['value']);

if($value=="Abracadabra" or strcmp($value,"Abracadabra")==0)
{
$result=1;
$image="src/abracadabra.jpg";
}
else
{
$result=0;
$image="src/photo1.jpg";
}

echo $result;
echo $image;
}
```

There, I want to "echo" two variables simultaneously to pass to $.ajax success function.

It is possible ? I don't refer to JSON, I refer only PHP with POST method.

Thank you

Comment: Could you combine them both into one string and split them up later again?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't refer to JSON"? You can easily return a JSON string from your PHP code instead of 0 or 1...

Comment: I didn't work with JSON anymore.

Comment: That's too bad, JSON would be the cleaner way to go on this exercise/case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the response from php code will be something like:

```
0src/photo1.jpg
```

and you will have to parse it with the javascript (probably with regex or substring)

```
success:function(data,data1) {
   var result = data.substring(0,1);
   var image = data.substring(1);
   // ... your code
}
```

**keep in mind** that it could cause you trouble if the `$result` variable is more than one character long :)

Comment: thank you Teneff, you opened my brain :D...I understand,if result is more than 1 character long (for example 3 characters), I will do : var result=data.substring(0,3) and var image=data.substring(3).I got it.

Answer (score 0):

have PHP echo a string like "value1|value2|etc" (or whatever other character(-sequence) is unlikely to wind up in the actual data)

then on the javascript side do a string.split('|') to break the returned string up into a neat little array.  you could even do key1:value1|key2:value2
and then use the solution [presented here to split the key:value pairs up into an object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086424/15118764)