# SpiderMonkey garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection, spidermonkey

If SM's GC is a conservative stack scanner, why is the [example 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey_Garbage_Collection_Tips) "bad"? Why is "root as you go" necessary? The GC should scan the stack and observe that str1, str2 are roots, no?

Comment: Who said it is a conservative stack scanner?

Comment: Yes, please do not rely on SpiderMonkey's collector to be conservative. Check out the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/10491571/3594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your timeline straight.

- A conservative stack scanner was [introduced in SpiderMonkey 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/1.8.5#Garbage_Collection).
- The document linked above also mentions 22 March 2011 as the release date of SpiderMonkey 1.8.5.
- The documentation you linked to [wasn't edited since August 2008](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey_Garbage_Collection_Tips%24history).

In other words: you found a piece of very outdated documentation. Indeed, the tags at the bottom say: `NeedsEditorialReview`, `NeedsTechnicalReview`. Not something that you should rely on.

Comment: `NeedsEditorialReview` Unfortunately that is how most of spidermonkey documentation marked :(

Comment: @dmitri: Editorial review isn't really important, technical review is. In fact, this particular article has a huge warning at the top now indicating that it is outdated.

Comment: Wladimir, could you recommend something to read on spidermonkey GC apart from source code?

Comment: @dmitri: I'm not a SpiderMonkey expert - I merely know a bit about how MDN works. For documentation I'd use Google, just like you.