# javascript string to object

Tags: javascript, string, object

How to apply string object value to a variable
Ex.

```
var str='{a:"www"}'
```

Now how to set

```
var obj={a:"www"}
```

I try eval() but not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to object in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: If at all possible, you should use valid JSON. eval() is rarely a good idea

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var str='{"a":"www"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Yes but now it does not corresponds to the requirement :)

Comment: FYI It should also work with eval. But it is not recommended to use eval for security reasons.

Comment: @trebuchet Thanks, why eval is a security risk?

Comment: for strings that were stored as JSON_stringify trebuchet solution works. I had string "{"1":["2013-05-10","3","#f70707"]}" and after JSON.parser I got Object {1: Array[3]}

Comment: @Ankit_Shah55 The only time eval becomes a problem is when User1's input is interpreted as javscript on User2.  User2 is then taken to a horrible pornography site and his wife walks in.  User2 then goes through a terrible divorce and never sees his children again.  But that's just one way.

Answer (score 41):

`eval` should work, and it's actually a [MDN solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility), not to mention that your string is not a valid JSON, so `eval` is your only option (if you don't want to include a library for that).

```
var str='{a:"www"}';
var obj=eval("("+str+")");
console.log(obj);
```

Quick test in Chrome Dev Tool:

```
eval("("+'{a:"www"}'+")")
Object
    a: "www"
    __proto__: Object
```

Just remember to wrap your string in parenthesis and assign it **outside** `eval` and it'll be (relatively) safe.

Comment: I wasn't wrapping mine in parentheses and I was getting an error.  Wrapping the object's string representation in parentheses before calling eval() worked for me too, but why are the parentheses necessary?

Comment: Is there a library to handle this?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) Those are needed to declare a function, which I guess is the same for an object. If you are passing a string containing a list of statements, it should work.

Comment: Awesome thank you! This should be the accepted answer