# Send multiple data params collected from string in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a string:

> '{format: "json", user: "user", password: "password"}'

and I want to send all this data using jQuery's AJAX. I've tried this way (requestData['data'] is the string) :

```
$.ajax({
     url: requestData['url'],
     type: requestData['type'],
     data: requestData['data'],
     error: function(xhr) {
         alert("failed");
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("success");
     }
});
```

Do I have to encode the string somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery AJAX and json format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426199/jquery-ajax-and-json-format)

Comment: _Do I have to encode the string somehow?_ It depends on what are you going to do with this data on server. BTW: your string is **not valid** JSON, so you can't decode it on server by standard means (`json_decode`)

Comment: Why it's not a valid JSON?

Comment: _Why it's not a valid JSON?_ Just read [the specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var datum = {
   format: "json",
   user: "user",
   password: "password"
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: url,          // your url
   dataType: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify(datum),
   success: function(response) {
      var result = response;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But imagine that I have a string, not a variable. The way you did it is great but it won't help me. I've tried to convert the string to object. Do you have any idea about how should I do it in the correct way?

Comment: This may help [javascript string to object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718326/javascript-string-to-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the whole object, its not a problem:

```
var jsonObj = {format: "json", user: "user", password: "password"};

$.ajax({
     url: requestData['url'],
     type: jsonObj,
     data: requestData['data'],
     error: function(xhr) {
         alert("failed");
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("success");
     }
});
```