# Get JavaScript object from database

Tags: javascript, database, object, serialization

I've a table in a SQL DB in which I store a JavaScript object like this:

```
{content: ['First paragraph','second paragraph']}
```

I get it from DB and try to pass to a function which needs an object formatted like it:

```
this._schedaService.getObjectFromDBToPrintPdf().subscribe(data => {
    pdfMake.createPdf(data).download('tempPdf.pdf');
});
```

The problem is that `data` is always a string.
I've tried `JSON.parse(data)` but (obviously) doesn't work.

If I write

```
cont temp = {content: ['First paragraph','second paragraph']};
```

it works.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Have you checked when you pass that 'data' , before that you're getting it? 
I suggest console it and then pass.

Comment: what if you `console.log` the string? What does it print? Perhaps you will need to apply a regex replace to wrap keys into double quotes, and replace single quotes with doubles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript string to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718326/javascript-string-to-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`JSON.parse`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) JavaScript function, *e.g.*

```
var data = JSON.parse("{content: ['First paragraph','second paragraph']}");
```

you will receive the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1

because your input string does not have a valid [JSON object syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp).

Your input string should have this format:

```
'{"content": ["First paragraph","second paragraph"]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in a tricky way: since [`JSON.parse`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) is a specific type of the [`eval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function, I just focused on JSON. The only solution (that I've found 'till now) is:

```
var str = "{content: ['First paragraph','second paragraph']}";
var obj = eval("(" + str + ")");
```

*N.B.* `typeof(obj)` returns

> object

Here is an useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718326/javascript-string-to-object).