# Angular 6 JSON deserializing

Tags: json, angular, json-deserialization, angular6

New to angular, i'm trying to do a simple thing! I'd like to convert a json to a specific object. Still doesn't work at this time.

The JSON is acquired from an url parameter "token" encoded in base64.

Here is the code:

```
this.decodedToken: ViewToken = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.DecodeBase64(this.token)));

console.log('token exists: ' + this.token);
console.log('token decoded: ' + this.decodedToken);            
console.log('token target: ' + this.decodedToken.target);
console.log('token access: ' + this.decodedToken.accessToken);
```

The target Object:

```
export class ViewToken {

    target: string;
    accessToken: string;

}
```

And here is the result:

```
token exists: ew0KICAgIHRhcmdldDogIm15VGFyZ2V0IiwNCiAgICBhY2Nlc3NUb2tlbjogIlRHOXlaVzBnYVhCemRXMGdaRzlzYjNJZ2MybDBJR0Z0WlhRc0lHTnZibk5sWTNSbGRIVnlJR0ZrYVhCcGMyTnBibWNnWld4cGRBPT0iDQp9 
token decoded: {
    target: "myTarget",
    accessToken: "TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdA=="
}
token target: undefined
token access: undefined
```

I tried many solutions but none of them worked! I still can't map the JSON to my object.

Solutions I tried so far:

- json2typescript package -> gives me error on the deserialize function
- fromJson method -> gives me a table of each character in the json

  ```
  static fromJson(json: any) {

      let obj: IViewToken = Object.create(ViewToken.prototype);

      return Object.assign(obj, json, {
          target: json.target,
          accessToken: json.accessToken
      });

  }
  ```
- object mapping key,value to object -> doesn't work since the json object attributes are undefined

**EDIT:**

Correction to make it work: I don't have to JSON.stringify my decoded base64 token

```
this.decodedToken = JSON.parse(this.DecodeBase64(this.token));
```

Comment: Your token isn't valid JSON, the keys aren't quoted. See the second answer on the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718664/3001761.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript string to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718326/javascript-string-to-object)

Comment: quoted keys or not, I have the same result :/

Comment: I doubt it, `JSON.parse('{"target": "myTarget", "accessToken": "TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgZWxpdA=="}')` works fine for me.

Comment: If I directly inject the json in the JSON.parse, it works indeed. But if I decode the json from the base64 encoded token, it dosn't! even with the quotes. I guess there is something I missing

Comment: What do you mean *"even with the quotes"*? If you're trying `this.decodedToken['target']` then of course that also doesn't work, it's not making any difference. The keys aren't quoted correctly **in the token**, so it can't be `JSON.parse`d properly. And when you stringify *then* parse it you end up right back where you started, that's a no-op.

Comment: Ok so this is indeed the JSON.stringify that gives me wrong results! Thakns for the help!