# Passing .net array to javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, arrays, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

I've read and tested hundreds of samples and suggestions, but none of them seem to work for me.

Using winForms webControl I'm trying to pass in to the google maps api an array of addresses where will make a stop on the way.

Without the stops array everything works just fine.
Here is the code samples:

JavaScript:

```
 function calcRoute(origin,destination, way ) 
 {
 var waypts = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < way.length; i++) {
             waypts.push({
              location:way[i],
              stopover:true});}
.....
```

VB.net

```
   Private Sub GetDirections_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        Dim origin As String = "1 Main St"
        Dim destination As String = "200 Main St"
        Dim wayP = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize({"123Main St.", "189 Main St"})
        InvokeScript("calcRoute", origin, destination, wayP)
    End Sub

    Private Function InvokeScript(name As String, ParamArray args As Object()) As Object
        Return WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(name, args)
    End Function
```

EDIT: the output I need to get in javascript is:

```
        [{
          location:"10201"
        },
        {
          location:"10202"
        }]
```

Comment: someone here has anything to add? any suggestion? –

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I added a sample array output in the question.

Comment: You're inputing an array of strings and expecting to get an array of objects out.  You need to create a simple class with a `location` property, and serialize an array of those objects.

Comment: after digging I see that the problem here is that javascript translate it to a string not a object, I guess I need to cast it or something on the javascript side.

Comment: Got it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js, @Smeegs please post you're comment as an answer so I could accept it and close that.

Comment: @Ezi, thanks :)  it's been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inputing an array of strings and expecting to get an array of objects out. You need to create a simple class with a location property, and serialize an array of those objects.