# Jquery .post(url,params) - how to use this if params is a string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem i dont know how to describe understandingly in the title, sorry for that. Hopefully it will come clearer in the text.

I already did an ajax post with jquery that worked fine. It was this:

```
var p1 = $.post(url,{what:"Add",d:dokid,u:seluserid});
p1.done(function(data){
...
```

Now, to copy that for another side(with a form) with a lots of radio buttons inside, i built the part in the {} as a string (paramlist) and tried to do the same. The resulting string paramlist:

```
paramlist = {what:"insert",ID:"-1",Name:"",Beschreibung:"",FieldX:"4",FieldY:"4",Roles:"4",FieldZ:"4",FieldN:"4"}
```

I got the FieldNames and Values by browsing to each radio element.

Now i am calling the .post by:

```
var p1 = $.post(url,paramlist);
p1.done(function(data){
...
```

This doesnt seem to work this way, for my php fails recognizing the post parameters.

```
$what=$_POST['what'];
```

gives me PHP Notice:  Undefined index: what...
So obviously i have to transform the string to something else. But how? I am out of search terms right now so i wanted to ask. The jquery api didn't help me. Maybe i am too much a newbie in all this stuff...
Any ideas?

What i did to get it to work:
removed the {} brackets from the string and put all elements in ". so now paramlist looks like:

```
paramlist = "what":"insert","ID":"-1","Name":"","Beschreibung":"","FieldX":"4","FieldY":"4","Roles":"4","FieldZ":"4","FieldN":"4"}
```

then convert the string to an object (with the help of [String to object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js)) using eval:

```
 objparamlist=eval('({' + paramlist + '})');
```

now calling

```
var p1 = $.post(url,objparamlist);
```

works.

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Stop building it as a string then, and create an object instead, and it will work

Comment: i did convert the string (a little modified) to an object , i'll edit above

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do them.. ..a little extrapolated, but easier to read.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/url.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        data: JSON.stringify(paramlist)
    },
    success: function.....
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this:

```
var p1 = $.post(url,{data: JSON.stringify(paramlist)});
```

Regards