# Converting string to object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, type-conversion

I am trying to convert to object this string.

```
   "JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js)

Comment: Write a parser to strip out `JwtBody` and then use JSON.parse().

Comment: @JaromandaX invalid as json due to no quotes

Comment: ahhh, yes, damn :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}" is obviously not a standard json string,So you can try this.

```
function strToObj(str){
   var obj = {};
   if(str&&typeof str ==='string'){
       var objStr = str.match(/\{(.)+\}/g);
       eval("obj ="+objStr);
   }
   return obj
}
```

Comment: or just `eval("JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}".replace(/([^}]+?)({.*})/, '$1=$2'));` - results in a var named JwtBody with the value of the object

Comment: Only `eval()` is not safe... If the string includes code, it's going to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)?

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like create a variable and use JSON.parse("string") to have it converted into an object.

So, for your example it would be something like:

```
var object = JSON.parse("JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}");
```

Comment: This will fail because the string is not well-formed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

You could try something like this:

```
var str = '{"user_id": "1", "auth_id": "1"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Be sure to have jquery like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can not use jQuery, in the backend I have a string as I said above and I need to convert it to an object.

Comment: The `1` don't need to be quoted. Actually, they probably should not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change data from example:

```
var parsedData = {};
var str = "JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}";

function getRawJSON(str){
    return str.split(' ').map((el, index)=>{return index>0 ? el : ''}).join('');
}

function formatingValidJSON(str){
    // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval
    return str
    .replace(/:\s*"([^"]*)"/g, function(match, p1) {
        return ': "' + p1.replace(/:/g, '@colon@') + '"';
    })
    .replace(/:\s*'([^']*)'/g, function(match, p1) {
        return ': "' + p1.replace(/:/g, '@colon@') + '"';
    })
    .replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?\s*:/g, '"$2": ')
    .replace(/@colon@/g, ':')
}

str = formatingValidJSON(getRawJSON(str));
try{
    parsedData = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log('Your parsed data:', parsedData);
}
catch(e){
    console.log('Your data is wrong');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSON-like string can be parsed using vanilla JavaScript and regex by:

1. Reducing string to only characters that [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) JSON-like object string
2. [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) property names to enclose matched names with quotations
3. parsing object with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

`var jwtBodyString = "JwtBody { user_id: 1, auth_id: 1}";`

```
`//1 match on only JSON within string
jwtBody = jwtBodyString.match(/{[^}]+}/).toString();`    

//2 enclose property names to prevent errors with JSON.parse()
jwtBody = jwtBody.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+):/g,'"$1":'));

//3 obtain object
var myJwtBodyObject = JSON.parse(jwtBody);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Also, you're javascript string is invalid JSON which means it's invalid javascript. It should look like this:

```
JSON.parse('{"jwtbody" : { "user_id" : 1, "auth_id" : 1}}');
```

This will give you  the corresponding javascript object you want.

Comment: This will fail because the string not in this format