# convert string to object when theres no comma separator

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a string as

```js
string = "name: my name 
           email: myemail
           address: my address";
```

Which will paste by the user. 
Now I want it to convert in object such that

```js
obj = {"name":"my name", "email":"myemail", "address":"my address"}
```

How can I do this in JS?

I already tried this 
[String to object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js)
but this only works when theres a comma separator.

Comment: Looks like a very X/Y problem. What's giving you that initial string? Best to fix it so it gives you proper JSON instead

Comment: Is the string multiline or is that a formatting problem?

Comment: the initial string is paste by the user in textarea field

Comment: Tell the user to input JSON instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this issue would be to nip it at the bud - send the object not a string. If that's not possible, then use `split` and `reduce` on the multiline string:

```js
const string = `name: my name 
email: myemail
address: my address`;
const res = string.split("\n").map(e => e.split(":").map(f => f.trim())).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v }), {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ECMAScript 2019 [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) function:

```js
const string = "name: my name\nemail: myemail\naddress: my address";

const object = Object.fromEntries(string.split(/\n/).map(s => s.split(/: /)));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a little coding challenge :)

```
const convertStrToObj = (str) =>
str.split('\n').reduce((result, field) => {
  const splitField = field.split(':')
  const fieldName = splitField[0].trim()
  const fieldValue = splitField[1].trim()
  return {
    ...result,
    [fieldName]: fieldValue
  }
}, {})
```