# TypeScript convert string to array of objects

Tags: typescript

How to cast string to array of objects in Type Script?

I have following code working perfectly:

```
let nodes = new DataSet<any>([
      {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
      {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
      {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
      {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
      {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]);
```

But when I try to use

```
let nodes2 = new DataSet<any>(this.someEntity.nodesConfig);
```

I get following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.   Type >'undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Here is SomeEntity:

```
export interface SomeEntity{
  id?: string;
  nodesConfig?: string;
  edgesConfig?: string;
}
```

Comment: possibly similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js

Comment: Try please let nodes2 = new DataSet<string>(this.someEntity.nodesConfig.split(””)); And you must check this.someEntity.nodesConfig before call DataSet

Comment: @PeterS JSON.parse() is a correct answer