# How do I convert a string which is in the form of Array of objects to JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string

This is my string

```
let data = "[{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Maryland Board ,Action Taken: Reprimand},{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Massachusetts Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board},{Date: 2007,Entity Taking Action: North Carolina Medical Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board action},{Date: 2013,Entity Taking Action: NC Medical Board,Action Taken: Letter of concern for not reporting previous NC consent order on reactivation of NC licence}]"
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js) is helpful?

Comment: You'll have to figure out how to parse that data string into an array of Javascript objects and then use `JSON.stringify()` on it. OR, if you got it from somebody, you can consider going back to them and asking them to give you real JSON instead.

Comment: @VedantBang I think JSON.parse would have helped if my key and values had quotes. But in this case its not working.

Comment: As you know, JSON is a standardized machine-readable way of representing data  like yours. But your data is not JSON.It's not even close.  It's something else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your best solution may be to ask the provider of that string not to think that what he provides is useful. There is high probability that it was some minor mistake or at least with very few effort on his side he can provide a better structured format (at least directly the yaml or something)
2. If you still have to doityourself you may

   - Try to convert the string as a jsonparsable one

```js
let data = "[{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Maryland Board ,Action Taken: Reprimand},{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Massachusetts Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board},{Date: 2007,Entity Taking Action: North Carolina Medical Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board action},{Date: 2013,Entity Taking Action: NC Medical Board,Action Taken: Letter of concern for not reporting previous NC consent order on reactivation of NC licence}]"
const t = data
  .replace(/([{,]\s*)([^{:]*)(:)/g, '$1"$2"$3') // replace keys
  .replace(/(:\s*)([^},]*)([,}])/g, (all, $1, $2, $3) => { // replace values
    let val = $2
    if (parseInt($2) != $2) {
      val = `"${$2}"`
    }
    return `${$1}${val}${$3}`
  }) // replace values
console.log('t : ', JSON.parse(t))
```

- Or parse it yourself

```js
let data = "[{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Maryland Board ,Action Taken: Reprimand},{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Massachusetts Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board},{Date: 2007,Entity Taking Action: North Carolina Medical Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board action},{Date: 2013,Entity Taking Action: NC Medical Board,Action Taken: Letter of concern for not reporting previous NC consent order on reactivation of NC licence}]"
const s = data.match(/{([^}]*)}/g).map(objStr => {
  const stripped = objStr.substring(1, objStr.length - 1)
  const o = stripped.split(',')
    .map(keyval => keyval.split(':'))
    .map(([k, v]) => {
      let val = parseInt(v)
      if (val != v) {
        val = v.trim()
      }
      return [k.trim(), val]
    })
  return Object.fromEntries(o)
})
console.log(s)
```

But recall that those are "tries" only since you don't know what kind of weird input your provider may give you in the future...

Comment: Doesn't works if my value data in string has comma :(
eg:-  

`
[{Date: 2005,Entity Taking Action: VA Dept of Health Professions,Action Taken: Due to DUI I was reprimanded, entered Recovery Monitoring Contract and HPIP and license of temporarily suspended. Contract was successfully completed and on 3/7/2008 full and unrestricted license was reinstated.}]
`

Comment: This was predictable as almost everybody told you : (. How would you differentiate a comma delimiting a json and a comma as text inside a value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your weird input data with a series of nested regular expressions, using [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and one [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
  const data = "[{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Maryland Board ,Action Taken: Reprimand},{Date: 2002,Entity Taking Action: Massachusetts Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board},{Date: 2007,Entity Taking Action: North Carolina Medical Board,Action Taken: Consent order because of Maryland Board action},{Date: 2013,Entity Taking Action: NC Medical Board,Action Taken: Letter of concern for not reporting previous NC consent order on reactivation of NC licence}]"
  const array = []
  console.log ('data', data);
  const regex1 = RegExp(/^\[(.*?)\]$/, 'g')
  while (true) {
    const rr1 = regex1.exec(data)
    if (!rr1) break
    const r1 = rr1[1]
    const regex2 = RegExp(/{(.+?)},?/, 'g')
    while (true) {
      let rr2 = regex2.exec(rr1)
      if (!rr2) break
      const r2 = rr2[1]
      const item = {}
      console.log('item', r2)
      const splits = r2.split(',')
      for (let key in splits) {
          let tagValue = splits[key]
          console.log ('tagValue', tagValue)
          const regex4 = RegExp(/ *(.+): *(.+) */, 'g')
          while (true) {
              const rr4=regex4.exec(tagValue)
              if (!rr4) break
              const tag = rr4[1]
              const val = rr4[2]
              item[tag] = val
              console.log ('field', tag, val)
          }
      }
      array.push(item)
      console.log ('item', item)
    }  
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(array))
```

The outermost `RegExp(/^\[(.*?)\]$/, 'g')` removes the `[]` delimiters.

The next one `RegExp(/{(.+?)},?/, 'g')` splits up your `{some thing},{another thing},{yet another}` data into `some thing`, `another thing`, and `yet another`, removing the `{}` curly braces as it does so.

The string.split turns your `Tag: value, Tag: value` sequence into individual `Tag: value` items.

And the innermost `RegExp(/ *(.+): *(.+) */, 'g')` turns those into `tag` and `val` items.

You know, it's said that if you solve a problem with a regular expression, you then have two problems. This solution uses three regular expressions, so now you have four problems. The point is that regular-expression parsing is brittle. For example, if one of your Action Taken items says `Disbarred, then thrown in federal prison`, that extra comma will wreck this parser.

You could write a robust parser for this stuff. But your better bet is to tell the provider of your data you need real JSON.