# How to convert String in to Object Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting response in a string array like this.

```
 {"columnModelObj":[{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_1","width":150,"text":"FILM"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_2","width":150,"text":"GENRE"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_3","width":150,"text":"LEAD STUDIO"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_4","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"AUDIENCE  SCORE %"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_5","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"PROFITABILITY"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_6","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"ROTTEN TOMATOES %"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_7","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"WORLDWIDE GROSS"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_8","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"YEAR"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_9","width":150,"text":"DATE"}],"recordModelObj":[{"name":"Film","type":"string"},{"name":"Genre","type":"string"},{"name":"Lead Studio","type":"string"},{"name":"Audience  score %","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Profitability","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Rotten Tomatoes %","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Worldwide Gross","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Year","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Date","type":"string"}]}
```

I have to make in to array object. Any possible idea how to make it.

Here is what I am doing but no luck.

```
var foo = col.split("\n").reduce(function(obj, str, index) {
  let strParts = str.split(":");
  if (strParts[0] && strParts[1]) { 
    obj[strParts[0].replace(/\s+/g, '')] = strParts[1].trim(); 
  }
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: It's JSON. Use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I have tried not working.

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 355

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Note that your "string" as posted is a syntax error anyway; you're nesting quotes improperly.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Ah. Where are you getting that content from? It is **not** valid JSON; those "renderer" properties are invalid. It *is* valid JavaScript, however, at least it looks like it is. How is that ending up in a string?

Comment: A similar question already exist (here) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js]

Answer (score 0):

well check this out

One simple code to fix your problems

```
data = ' {"columnModelObj":[{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_1","width":150,"text":"FILM"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_2","width":150,"text":"GENRE"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_3","width":150,"text":"LEAD STUDIO"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_4","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"AUDIENCE  SCORE %"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_5","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"PROFITABILITY"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_6","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"ROTTEN TOMATOES %"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_7","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"WORLDWIDE GROSS"},{"filter":{"type":"number"},"renderer":formatGridNumberColumn,"dataIndex":"_8","showOriginalData":true,"width":150,"text":"YEAR"},{"filter":{"type":"list"},"multiValueTextData":true,"dataIndex":"_9","width":150,"text":"DATE"}],"recordModelObj":[{"name":"Film","type":"string"},{"name":"Genre","type":"string"},{"name":"Lead Studio","type":"string"},{"name":"Audience  score %","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Profitability","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Rotten Tomatoes %","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Worldwide Gross","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Year","allowNull":true,"type":"number"},{"name":"Date","type":"string"}]}'

data = data.split("formatGridNumberColumn").join('"formatGridNumberColumn"')

data_object = JSON.parse(data)
```

and Data_object is the object you are looking for

you see the villain here is the formatGridNumberColumn which in not qouted " ". So the parsed result can never be a string.

Alone the formatGridNumberColumn is foreign to javascript.

for that reason I split the string by formatGridNumberColumn and joind it again by "formatGridNumberColumn". As it beacame a string now JSON can parse it.