# JavaScript Adding New property to Object shows in double quote

Tags: javascript, properties, canvasjs

I want to add a new property to my Object. But it adds the property in double-quotes and the object is not able to initialize well.
Here is my code in the JSFiddle.

Here what I expect is like [image: Expectation]

This is how it comes [image: Not correct]

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

```js
var chart;
function myFunction(incoming_data) {
var lcl = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(incoming_data));
var headertxt = lcl.title_dynamic;
console.log(headertxt);
var chartCfg = {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            axisX: {
                title: "chart updates every 2 secs",
                crosshair: {
                    enabled: true,
                    snapToDataPoint: true
                }
            },
            axisY: {
                crosshair: {
                    enabled: true,
                    snapToDataPoint: true,
                    valueFormatString: "#,##0"
                }
            },
            toolTip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                dockInsidePlotArea: true,
                verticalAlign: "top",
                horizontalAlign: "right"
            }
        };
chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart-container", chartCfg);
        chart.options.title = headertxt;
console.log(chart.options);
        chart.render();
}
var json_val = {"title_dynamic":"{text:\"Header Tay\"}"};
myFunction(json_val);
```

```html
  <div id="chart-container" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
<div style="margin-top:16px;color:dimgrey;font-size:9px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration:none;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.stock.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: I attached the code snippet.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]`snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: `headertxt` *is* text, as the variable name suggests. You need: `JSON.parse(headertxt)`.

Comment: @VLAZ I get the following error when I use as you suggessted  ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1```

Comment: Ah, right, it's *not* JSON, just a weird text version of a JS object, for some reason. The easiest immediate fix is to `eval` it but I'd *very heavily suggest*, you change whatever is generating that data to produce valid JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ I use the CanvasJS object tho. So, this is its object. I am passing the ```headertext``` by the controller. I will also pass the ```data``` by the controller. They have to be dynamic according to selected parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was so simple. In case any of the fellas have a similar issue I post my solution.

Convert a string to object

```
var my_obj = eval('({' + txt+ '})');
```

Convert data to an array

```
var my_obj = eval(var_array);
```

Reference questions: [String to object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js)
[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Cheers!